# Is it possible to enable adress bar in Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus

I stopped to use Ubuntu a few years ago. If I Install the new version 18.04, will it be possible to leave Nautilus with address bar instead path bar? Does `dconf` still work for such tasks on new Ubuntu Bionic Beaver? Nautilus open terminal it's out of Ubuntu 18.04 , because was a good tool?